# Problem with row selection in extendedDataTable

Tags: datatable, richfaces, selection

I have a problem with extendedDataTable in richfaces. I am trying to select one row in a extendedDataTable and the selection works. This is some code that I am using.

```
...
    <rich:extendedDataTable id="dt2_documenti_a4" styleClass="tableLeft"
                rowClasses="row1,row2" rows="10" value="#{formCarriBombolaiDettaglioInterventoBean.elencoErogazioni}" var="doc" 
                selectionMode="single">
                    <a4j:ajax event="selectionchange" execute="@this"/>
                    <a4j:ajax listener="#{carriBombolaiPMIBean.updateCheckboxErogazioneEvPub(doc)}" event="selectionchange" 
                            render="dt2_documenti_a4, calcoli_preventivo_ev_pub, mod_preventivo, panel_preventivi"/>
    ...
```

The problem is that the variable `doc`, when passed to the method `carriBombolaiPMIBean.updateCheckboxErogazioneEvPub(doc)` is null. Someone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doc` variable is only meaningful when the table rows are being rendered (or traversed), since the `selectionchange` event is triggered on table level it will be null.

You need keep track of the selected rows and get the selected row from the table based on that:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable selection="#{carriBombolaiPMIBean.selection}" … >
```

…

```
private Collection<Object> selection;
private List<Item> selectionItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    AbstractExtendedDataTable dataTable = (AbstractExtendedDataTable) event.getComponent();
    Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();
    selectionItems.clear();
    for (Object selectionKey : selection) {
        dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey);
        if (dataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
            selectionItems.add((Item) dataTable.getRowData());
        }
    }
    dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);
}
```

For a full example see the [row selection demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection) in the Showcase.